# C: Return correct value, but assign wrong value: -1.#IND000000000000

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a problem when using double variable type. In sub function, returned value is `mid = 1.0306534300317196`. But when assign this value to `coord[0]`. But `coord[0]=-1.#IND000000000000`. 
I really don't understand why it is wrong.
Please help me to clear it. Thank you!

```
     #include <stdio.h>
double x[11];
double m[11];

double coord[9];

double abs(double a, double b){
    if(a>b)
        return a-b;
    else return b-a;
}
double findCoord(double left, double right) {
    double mid = (left + right)/2;
    //double oldmid =0;
    double f_left = 0;
    double f_right = 0; 

    f_left= f_left + m[0]/((mid-x[0]) * (mid-x[0]));

    f_right= f_right + m[1]/((x[1]-mid) * (x[1]-mid));

    // check errors of value ?????
    if(abs(f_right,f_left)<0.000000001)
        return mid;
    // check by F
    if (f_left==f_right)
        return mid;
    if (f_left > f_right){
        left=mid;   
        findCoord(left, right);
    }
    if (f_left < f_right){
        right=mid;  
        findCoord(left, right);
    }           
}   
int main(void)
{
    x[0]=1;
    x[1]=2;
    m[0]=1;
    m[1]=1000;

    coord[0]=findCoord(x[0], x[1]);


    printf("%.10f \n", coord[0]);

    while(1);
    return 0;//Your program should return 0 on normal termination.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should employ

```
return findcoord(left,right);
```

Instead of

```
findcoord(left,right);
```

inside the function findcoord for recursive calls otherwise the value the recursive calls to function returns is lost!

Answer (score 1):

For the last 2 condition in findCoord func, you don't return any things and give just call function. Return statement just return the mid value to its previous calling function. In the recursive system, function call itself many times. According to you code, It just return mid value to the previous 1 step back but not for all previous call. So, use

```
return findCoord(left, right);
```

Answer (score 0):

`findCoord()` returns a value if `abs(f_right,f_left)<0.000000001` or `f_left==f_right`. If neither of these are true, then no value is returned.

Ensure all code paths in `findCoord()` return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile your code with -Wall option. It will give you some important warnings

```
test.c:23:8: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘abs’
 double abs(double a, double b){
        ^
test.c: In function ‘findCoord’:
test.c:52:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
```

Those warnings means that:

1. you cannot use the buildin function name abs for your function
2. Your function needs to return always a value, if declared non void.

A solution could be

```
double myabs(double a, double b){
    if(a>b)
        return a-b;
    else return b-a;
}
double findCoord(double left, double right) {
    double mid = (left + right)/2;
    //double oldmid =0;
    double f_left = 0;
    double f_right = 0;

    f_left= f_left + m[0]/((mid-x[0]) * (mid-x[0]));

    f_right= f_right + m[1]/((x[1]-mid) * (x[1]-mid));

    // check errors of value ?????
    if(myabs(f_right,f_left)<0.000000001)
        return mid;
    // check by F
    if (f_left==f_right)
        return mid;
    if (f_left > f_right){
        left=mid;
        return findCoord(left, right);
    }
    if (f_left < f_right){
        right=mid;
        return findCoord(left, right);
    }

    return 0; // Gcc happy :)
}
```